# how to make UIAlertView with custom font , height and width?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I want to show pop up of question with it's options.
Each question have 3 options. 
Currently the text is not fitting in the UIAlertView.
My UIalertView is in landscape mode.

my questions are,

1) How to change the font and font size of UIAlertView message and Button?

2) How to increase the height and width of UIAlertView?

OR please suggest me any other way , by which I implement the same pop up.

Thanks .

Comment: You have asked 22 questions, none of which you have marked as answered. As a courtesy to those who take the time to answer your questions, please fix this.

Comment: Shreya, please read the FAQ, so you can get a better understanding of how Stack Overflow works as a community. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better idea might be to make a custom `UIView` (that you can design in Interface Builder) and have that "pop up" by adding/removing it as a subview from the current view.